# Can you talk via IP/TCP without internet?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I want to know if you can use a socket() to communicate directly between two computers, with an Ethernet cable directly connecting 1 computer's port to the other.

The issue being, since neither computer is connecting to a router, there's nothing to give either computer an IP address.

Is it possible to make a socket without an IP address?

Comment: That could need special tips on both sides of cable such as shifted or inverted order pins for windows. Better ask at superuser branch of stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the right software, you can assign the computers internal IP, and make them communicate. It all depends on your network, and how it handles addresses assignments.

The only concern using addresses is to make the sender know the address and make sure the reciever uses that address as his own.

If you decide, for example, that Computer 1 has IP `0.0.0.1` and Computer 2 has IP `0.0.0.2`, you can have a conversation (inside your own little peer to peer network).

Comment: So if I manually assign an IP address, is there any restriction on what the address should be? For example, if 1 computer is only connecting to the other, but the second computer has a wifi connection, and therefore has a valid IP address, can I pick any address I want to the unconnected computer, or will that break things if I don't choose correctly?

Comment: If one of them or both has also internet connection, overlapping addresses may be a problem. In that case you will have to use some unique ips (possibly from the normally unused ranges) to make sure they will not try to connect to other devices, or make sure they communicate with their ips only inside their p2p connection.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a router for two computers to communicate over TCP/IP or UDP. They only need IP addresses. There are three mechanisms how they can get an IP address:

1. DHCP, which is typically what happens when you plug into a router or connect to a Wifi network.
2. Manual IP configuration, in which you explicitly configure a static IP address for each network interface.
3. [Self-assigned link-local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Address_autoconfiguration), which is what modern operating systems usually resort to when they don't get any help from a DHCP server.

Most likely, your two computers would resort to #3 and assign themselves an IP address in the 169.254.x range. Your only problem then is discovering what IP addresses were actually assigned.  You can use your platform's command-line `ifconfig`/`ipconfig` tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

> since neither computer is connecting to a router

### Brief networking lesson

A router is only necessary to *route* packets, as its name suggests. That means to make those packets hop, i.e. to pass them to the next network segment.
In your case, you don't need any network hop, since you want to comunicate within a LAN (Local Area Network). In order for two computers with no Internet connection to intercommunicate, it's enough to assign a static IP address to each computer and connect them with an Ethernet cable. This way, you'll be actually creating a network between them.

#### What IP address will be valid?

Every IP address is one only number. IPv4 addresses are 32-bit numbers, whereas IPv6 ones are 128–bit. The dot notation used to write them (e.g. 127.0.0.1) encodes this number as four octets, using the network byte order (big endian). IPv6 addresses are written using six octets and those octets are written using the hexadecimal numbering system, as opposed to the decimal used for IPv4.

A network interface or network driver, depending on whether the hardware interface implements the transport layer, rejects any IP packet whose source address doesn't fit the subnet that you have set for the receiving interface. What does it mean to *fit* a subnet? A subnet mask is a bit mask under the hood, yet it may not look like that due to it being written using the dot notation the same way as any IP address. Therefore, to check whether an IP address `A` fits a network given its base address `B` and its netmask `C`, operate a bitwise AND between `A - B` and `C`; the IP address fits the network if and only if `(A - B) & C = (A - B)`. A network base address and a subnet mask are used to identify the network segment a node (e.g. a computer) is in. To represent both in a single, concise way, the CIDR notation has been invented — it consists of the network base address followed by the number of leading 1 bits in the network mask. For instance, 127.0.0.0/8 represents a network with base address 127.0.0.0 and netmask 255.0.0.0.
When a network node sends an IP packet, every node in the network receives it at hardware–level. Then, if the destination address fits the subnet set for the node with that address, that node will actually receive the packet; otherwise, if that node is not a router, the packet will be ignored; if it is and this router is also set as the default gateway of the source interface, the packet will be routed to the next network segment, hoping that the destination node is there.
For instance, you have one computer in your home LAN and your home network consists of a modem/router: the latter acts as a gateway to route packets from your computer to the Internet. But if your computer sends a TCP packet to another computer within your LAN, the router won't do anything and the packet will be received by the destination node regardless of whether there is router — there's nothing to route.

### Back to the original question

You want two computers to intercommunicate within a LAN, one only of which is connected to a broader network giving it Internet access. This means that you'll not want to change the IP address or subnet of the computer with Internet access, but you can set anything arbitrary to the other computer.
Let's say the IP address of the computer in the broader network is 192.168.1.100 and its network is 192.168.1.1/24. In order for the other computer to communicate, its network has to intersect 192.168.1.1/24 and the intersection has to contain both the source IP address and the destination one for packets sent to be received. Then it'll be enough to choose an IP address like 192.168.1.101 and a network like 192.168.1.100/31, without any default gateway.